# Errors don't prevent object from saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a virtual attribute that takes a time range from a form field and splits it:

```
def time_range=(time_range)
  unless time_range.empty?
    t = time_range.split(/to|\-/)
    self.start_entry = t[0]
    self.finish_entry = t[1]
    if Chronic.parse(self.start_entry).nil? || Chronic.parse(self.finish_entry).nil?
      errors.add(:time_range, 'Invalid time range entered')
    end
  end
end
```

`start_entry` and `finish_entry` are also virtual attributes as I have other ways to set them. Regardless of how the two were set, I have the following hook to set `start` and `finish` in my database:

`before_save :set_start_and_finish`

Despite the fact that I add an error, erroneous objects still manage to save:

```
> t = Tour.new
> t.time_range = "rubbish"
> t.errors
#=> {:time_range=>["Invalid time range entered"]}
> t.valid?
#=> true
```

How can I invalidate the instance to prevent it from saving later?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling `t.valid?` will clear the errors before running the validations so your validations inside `time_range=` are ignored.

If we look at [ActiveRecords's `valid?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L68), we see this:

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  context ||= (new_record? ? :create : :update)
  output = super(context)
  #...
```

And the super should send you into [ActiveModel's `valid?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L311) which starts like this:

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  #...
```

and the `clear` call nukes the errors you added in `time_range=`.

If you want to validate something, use the validators. If you want to prevent an invalid assignment, raise an [ArgumentError](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ArgumentError.html) (or other more appropriate exception).

Having the validation system reset itself (i.e. `errors.clear`) before running the validations does make sense. If it didn't reset, you'd have to throw away and reload an invalid object (or manually reset it) just to correct a validation error. Just because "update, validate, save or destroy" is the general workflow for a web-app doesn't mean that it is the only possible workflow for a database-backed application.

Comment: Insightful, thanks! Raising an exception is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

`set_start_and_finish` seems like an odd place to be checking for validation errors, but make sure that you are returning `false` if you detect an error to stop the rest of the callbacks from executing.

[Read the section on "Cancelling callbacks"](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: I know it's a bit odd, but it seems that validating inside the setter for `time_range` is best because it sets shared virtual attributes. 

I tried having my callback return `false` if it found any errors, but this didn't work inside `set_start_and_finish`: `false if self.errors.presence`. Wrong approach?

Comment: What version of Rails is this, and can you post the real code please? Also, something is missing from your last example, because there's no call to `save` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `set_start_and_finish` on validate instead of `before_save`
As 
`validate :set_start_and_finish`